# How can i reset a JProgressBar in java?

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I have a button and when i click it, then it will start the `progressbar`. After finishing one time, i want the progressbar to reset and if i click on the button again then it will start fresh. 
**Here's my code:**

```
else if (action == detectButton) {

            // pb.setVisible(true);

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pb.setValue(0);
                    pb.repaint();
                }
            });

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int val = i;
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setValue(val);
                        pb.repaint();
                        try {
                            java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });

            }
```

Now the problem is that when i first run it runs ok but in second attempt it is not resetting the progressbar to 0. **How to do it actually??**

**EDIT:** **I am repainting the progressbar everytime but i saw that it is not smooth enough to show that 10% happened then 20%..**

Comment: What **is** happening the second attempt?

Comment: once the progressbar is finished one time then if i click it second time then the progress remain full i.e it doesn't reset

Comment: Can you add more code to your question? You've posted a runnable the resets the progress bar in its own thread and waits a full two seconds, meanwhile a for-loop runs 10 new runnables

Answer (score 0):

Your JProgressbar doesn't reset, because it will be repaint after the first Runnable finished. But your `java.lang.Thread.sleep(2000);` prevent this.

Comment: I deleted the line but the same condition.. once the progressbar is full then if i click the button again it is remaining full. I tried by giving sleep() in the forloop also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example, how to use the progressbar:

```
public class TestWindow
{

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestWindow()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Reset");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 228, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton button = new JButton("Run");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Runnable update = new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
                        {
                            final int val = i;

                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    progressBar.setValue(val);
                                    progressBar.repaint();
                                }

                            });

                            try
                            {
                                java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e1)
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(update);
                t.start();
            }
        });

        button.setBounds(109, 228, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        progressBar.setValue(0);
                        progressBar.repaint();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: so i have to use two buttons for running it and resetting it.. Can't i do it in one button press?? or simply hiding the progressbar on finishing it and showing the button on starting again from initial state??